# if a user tries an option, and the option is not right, go back to a certain point and try again - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a quiz game for a school project and I want to make it so that when the user inputs an invalid command, it goes back and tries the input to goto that menu again and brings up the exact same input box and tries the code again. I will post a part where I want this to happen.

```
#---->TO HERE
if userinput == str("help"):
    print ("This is the help menu")
    print ("This is how you play")
else:
    print ("Invalid Command")
#This is where I want the user to go back and try entering a command again to get the same code to run through again. 
#FROM HERE <----
```

Comment: If you're using Python 2, you should get rid of the parentheses in your print statements. If you're using Python 3, you should get rid of the space before the opening parenthesis. Whichever you're using `str("help")` is exactly equivalent, functionally, to `"help"`, but less efficient.

Answer (score 5):

```
while True:
    userinput = input()
    if userinput == 'help':
        print('This is the help menu')
        print('This is how you play')
        break
    else:
        print('Invalid command')
```

The `while` loop is used for situations like these. The `break` statement allows you to 'break' out of a `while` or `for` loop. A `while True` loop will loop forever, unless it encounters the `break` statement.

There is also a `continue` statement which allows you to skip the rest of the loop and go back to the beginning, but there's no need to use it here.

See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) for further reading.

Comment: I don't like infinite loops with `break`s. Check out my solution. Still, +1 for a working solution and explanation

Comment: You're assuming Python 3; for Python 2, it would be `raw_input()` instead of `input()` and `print x` instead of `print(x)`.

Comment: Since this is the help menu and even if the command is valid, I want it to go back to the input box & display a main menu again so you can input play game or another option and continue the game more. This solution only goes back to the input box twice if the command is invalid.

Comment: Would i just take out the break in this case? I'm fairly new to python so all help is great.

Comment: Ya I took out the break and got exactly what I wanted. Thanks, you were a good help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a fan of infinite loops with `break`s, so here's something that I like better:

```
validCommands = ['help']
userInput = None
while userInput not in validCommands:
    userInput = input("enter a command: ").strip()
handleInput(userInput)

def handleInput(userInput):
    responses = {'help':['This is the help menu', 'This is how you play']
                }
    print('\n'.join(responses[userInput]))
```

Comment: I find that infinite loops are cleaner - it's really just personal preference I guess. +1 for using a list though - it's much easier than writing a lot of `if-elif` statements if you have a lot of possible commands

Comment: Well, in my implementation, `handleInput` will have a bunch of `elif`s anyways. But, I fixed that in the update

Comment: SyntaxError: invaid syntax (QuizGame.py line 27) Which is the bottom of yours here.

print '\n'.join(responses[userInput])

Comment: @user1973446: works fine for me. I just tested it. What version of python are you using?

Comment: Try it now. I just ported it to python3 (was in python2.7 syntax before)

Comment: Python 3.3 & it says handleInput is not defined. that is because you need to do handleInput = (userInput) I did that, but nothing happens when I type help (I guess that's supposed to happen, and there is a forever loop when an invalid command is entered. So thanks, did what I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

```
questions = {
    'quiz_question_1': quiz_question_1,
    'quiz_question_2': quiz_question_2
}


def runner(map, start):
    next = start

    while True:
    questions = map[next]
    next = questions()

# whatever room you have set here will be the first one to appear
runner(questions, 'quiz_question_1') 

def quiz_question_1():
 a = raw_input(">")

 if a == "correct answer"
  return "quiz_question_2"

 if a == "incorrect answer"
  return "quiz_question_1"
```

you can add more "rooms" to the in the squiggly brackets. Just make sure that the last room
does NOT have a comma, and that they are in order in which they appear in the code.